# what is "<<<<<<< head" in my files?

Tags: git, phpstorm

I was working on a PHP project in PHPStorm, now after pulling a commit of a friend if found lots of `<<<<<<< HEAD` and `>>>>>>>` in my code, what are these and who added them?

Answer (score 9):

These symbols delimit a conflict in an merge performed on this file. You have to resolve the conflict, then create a new commit.

There is plenty of resources to learn how to resolve git conflicts. For example, https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/ from GitHub is a good starting point.

Comment: PHPStorm has a better tool for resolve git conflict than commandline tool